# Subtracting times in a csv for a row by row basis in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I have a CSV that's few thousand rows long. It contains data sent from various devices. They should transmit frequently (every 10 minutes) however sometimes there is a lag. I'm trying to write a program that will highlight all instances where the delay between two readings is greater than 15 minutes

I've made a functional code that works, but with this code I first have to manually edit the CSV to change the "eventTime" variable from time format (e.g. 03:22:00) to a float value based on 1/24 (e.g. 03:22:00 becomes 0.14027). Similarly, the 15 minute interval becomes 0.01042 (15/(60*24))

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
deviceID = df["deviceId"].unique().tolist()
threshold = 0.01042
for id_no in range(0, len(deviceID)):
    subset = df[df.deviceId == deviceID[id_no]]
    for row in range(len(subset)-1):
        difference = subset.iloc[row, 1] - subset.iloc[row+1, 1]
        if difference > threshold:
            df2 = df2.append(subset.iloc[row])
            df2 = df2.append(subset.iloc[row+1])

df2.to_csv('file2.csv)
```

This works, and I can open the CSV in excel and manually change the float values back to time format, but when I might be dealing with a few hundred CSV files, this becomes impractical,

I've tried this below

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
deviceID = df["deviceId"].unique().tolist()
df['eventTime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S"))
threshold = datetime.strptime("00:15:00", '%H:%M:%S')
for id_no in range(0, len(deviceID)):
    subset = df[df.deviceId == deviceID[id_no]]
    for row in range(len(subset)-1):
        difference = datetime.strptime(subset.iloc[row, 1],'%H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(subset.iloc[row+1, 1], '%H:%M:%S')
        if difference > threshold:
            df2 = df2.append(subset.iloc[row])
            df2 = df2.append(subset.iloc[row+1])

df2.to_csv('file2.csv')
```

but I get the following error:

```
if difference > threshold:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

The data looks like this:

```
| eventTime|  deviceId|
| -------- | -------- |
| 15:30:00 |  11234889|
| 15:45:00 |  11234889|
| 16:00:00 |  11234889|
```

and for different IDs

```
| eventTime|  deviceId|
| -------- | -------- |
| 15:30:00 |  11234890|
| 15:45:00 |  11234890|
| 16:00:00 |  11234890|
```

Comment: Let's say your initial time was `15:30:00`. If the next time in line is `15:48:00`, which is more than 15 minutes and is to be highlighted, what would the next expected time be? Is it `16:00:00` or `16:03:00`? This is a very important distinction.

Comment: @WitchGod If the time is 15:48:00, then the expected next time would be 16:03:00, the devices are not bound by any central clock (e.g. they're not sending based on a fixed schedule), they're supposed to transmit every 15 minutes, so if one loses signal for an hour, it should carry on every 15 minutes from when it comes back online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`threshold` is `datetime` and you compare it to `timedelta` object (`difference`). Did you mean:

```
from datetime import timedelta
...
threshold = datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
```

Comment: Do you also know how I could an extra line or two to include the difference? I don't think adding `df2 = df2.append(difference)` would work here

Answer (score 0):

Given this dataframe:

```
  actual_ts    id
0  05:00:00  SPAM
1   5:15:00  SPAM
2   5:33:00  SPAM <-- Should highlight
3   5:45:00  SPAM
4   6:02:00  SPAM <-- Should highlight
5  11:15:00   FOO
6  11:32:00   FOO <-- Should highlight
7  11:45:00   FOO
8  12:08:00   FOO <-- Should highlight
```

This is a step-by-step way of getting to where you want, definitely not the most optimal but it's clear enough to teach you how to avoid looping over dataframes, which is a major no-no. Try running and printing the dataframe every step so you know what's happening.

```
# Convert column to timedelta.
df["actual_ts"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["actual_ts"])

# Sort as a best practice if not computationally expensive.
df = df.sort_values(by=["id", "actual_ts"])

# Shift the actual_ts by one row per group.
df["lagged_ts"] = df.groupby(["id"])["actual_ts"].shift(1)

# Fill nulls with same time if you want to avoid NaNs and NaTs.
df["lagged_ts"] = df["lagged_ts"].fillna(df["actual_ts"])

# Calculate difference in seconds.
df["diff_seconds"] = (df["actual_ts"] - df["lagged_ts"]).dt.seconds

# Mark as True all events greater than 15 minutes.
df["highlight"] = df["diff_seconds"] > 900

# Keep all columns you need.
new_df = df[["actual_ts", "id", "diff_seconds", "highlight"]]
```

You get this:

```
        actual_ts    id  diff_seconds  highlight
5 0 days 11:15:00   FOO             0      False
6 0 days 11:32:00   FOO          1020       True
7 0 days 11:45:00   FOO           780      False
8 0 days 12:08:00   FOO          1380       True
0 0 days 05:00:00  SPAM             0      False
1 0 days 05:15:00  SPAM           900      False
2 0 days 05:33:00  SPAM          1080       True
3 0 days 05:45:00  SPAM           720      False
4 0 days 06:02:00  SPAM          1020       True
```

Cleaning up the `0 days` is up to you. You can also change `diff_seconds` to minutes but that's easy enough.